# Как сделать, чтобы часть скрипта прошла перед началом сцены?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Как сделать, чтобы часть скрипта прошла перед началом сцены?
Нужно, чтобы когда началась игра, часть скрипта создающего деревья на заднем фоне прошла. как сделать?

Comment: Зачерните экран (или выведите любой экран загрузки), пока загружается сцена и создаются деревья и все остальное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов любого `Awake()` метода осуществляется до вызова всех методов `Start()`.

Это означает что если засунуть нужные действия в Awake то они проработаются до инициализации обьектов методами Start(). То есть это будет во время загрузки сцены, фактически.

Если же интересует конкретно подгрузка иной сцены в бэкграунде, то делаешь вот так:

```
var loader = Application.LoadLevelAsync("somelevel");
loader.allowSceneActivation = false;
```

а потом переключаешь в нужный момент сцену вот так:

```
loader.allowSceneActivation = true;
```

Comment: А нельзя, просто установить, чтобы должно пройти 50 секунд и все. А сцена запускается с 50 секунды??

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Comment: Прекрасно, это пауза. А чтобы сцена программно начиналась с 50 секунды, без паузы можно?

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема вызвать `loader.allowSceneActivation = true;` после 50й секунды, как УЖЕ написано у меня в ответе изначально?

Comment: В том что это у меня единственная сцена. И делать перезапуск с сцены с таймингом в 50 секунд не комильфо

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что должно выйти и как это должно выглядеть, но, судя по всему, подойдет только создание новой пустой стартовой сцены + LoadingScreen при запуске даной сцены с уровнем.